# How to redefine layout for custom page

Tags: ruby, layout, yaml, nanoc

I use nice a site-generator on ruby nanoc (http://nanoc.stoneship.org/). I need to redefine the layout for rendering some pages. Maybe it can be determined directly in yaml config?

For example, I have some layout (`my_layout.html`), but I want to create several blank pages (with `blank.html` layout).

Answer (score 2):

[This is in the doc.](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/4-basic-concepts/#compilation-rules)

You need to add `layout 'blank'` in the `compile` rule for the concerned pages.

Comment: I meant, how to do that without changing compile rule every time you need to do that?

Comment: Well it depends how many pages and how you can name them... I guess you could pick a layout depending on some attribute of the page as well, similarly to [this](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/6-guides/#using-filters-based-on-file-extensions)…

Comment: No problem. Can you edit your question so that it makes more sense to other readers with the same problem?